# How to create multiple subscriptions for a single topic in a GCP using terraform scripts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

Currently, I have a pub-sub topic, for which I have to create multiple subscribers which access messages published on that topic. l am using terraform scripts to create the subscription. This script is used to create a single subscriber for a topic. How can I modify the script to include multiple subscriber?

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "example-1" {
name = "example-1"
topic = "{{topic-id}}"
labels = {
application   = var.app_name
business_unit = var.business_unit
contact_email = var.contact_email
name          = var.app_name
owner         = var.owner
}
message_retention_duration = "1200s"
retain_acked_messages      = true
filter = "attributes.KEY = \"value\""
ack_deadline_seconds = 20

retry_policy {
  minimum_backoff = "180s"
}

enable_message_ordering    = true
}
```

Comment: "multiple subscribers" - its not clear? They are completely identical subscribers? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. I have a pub-sub topic, for which I have to create multiple subscribers which access messages published on that topic. l am using terraform scripts to create the subscription. This script is used to create a single subscriber for a topic

Comment: Did you manage to add the count to `google_pubsub_subscription` as I instructed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [count](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count). For example to create 3 subscriptions:

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "example" {

  count = 3 

name = "example-${each.key}"
topic = "{{topic-id}}"
labels = {
application   = var.app_name
business_unit = var.business_unit
contact_email = var.contact_email
name          = var.app_name
owner         = var.owner
}
message_retention_duration = "1200s"
retain_acked_messages      = true
filter = "attributes.KEY = \"value\""
ack_deadline_seconds = 20

retry_policy {
  minimum_backoff = "180s"
}

enable_message_ordering    = true
}
}
```

Comment: does count act like a loop? what is the value of each.key?

Comment: @KoushikJ yes, its a loop which will create 3 subscriptions. each.key will be 0,1,2. Please check docks I linked.